# Permission denied with embeded tomcat

Tags: java, spring, permissions, embedded-tomcat-7

I have a Spring boot application  which tries to access files located in "/var/someDirectory"

Platform is: linux ubuntu 16

Server Application is: **Embedded** tomcat

here is the code:

```
    File file = new File("/var/testFile1.txt");
    if (file.createNewFile()) {
        System.out.println("File is created!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("File already exists.");
    }
```

but with exception:

> java.io.IOException: Permission denied

Question:

How can I grant permissions to my application on '/var/'  ?

Comment: did you try with sudo ?

Comment: I don't want my app to run with root permissions,
I want to give it  permissions on a specific directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo mkdir /var/someDirectory
sudo chown -R your_user /var/someDirectory
```

It is not about Java, honestly.